# Mix fonts in font set on website

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, webfonts, typeface

Is it possible to mix 2 sets of different fonts into a fontset for use?

For example, I only want to use the symbols/numericals from font A and use roman alphabets of Font B

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many font sets as you want in a website. Your just going to end up using lots and lots of classes.

```
<div class="mydiv roman">My content will be roman</div>
<div class="mydiv symbols">My content will be symbols</div>

CSS


.roman {
    font-family: 'Whatever Font';
 }
```

Comment: You may also want to try using Font-squirrel you may be able to mix two fonts together.

Comment: Might have misunderstood my question, I don't want the hassle of having to wrap every word that needs to be in a different font with a div. Need to be able to detect if symbols such as '!', '?', '1 2 3', it would automatically use different font.